# How to atomatically delete specs of terminated children in a dynamic supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

*No knowledge of USB needed for this question, just described it as it is to make the example more conrete.*

I'm trying to implement a dynamic supervisor for specific devices on a USB bus.
These devices have addresses and appear and disappear during the lifetime of the system.

For each device I need a dynamic child for my supervisor.

These children are transient, so once they crash or terminate we don't restart them (because probably they are gone then).

I have a process that scans the USB port at certain times and produces a list of all addresses of the USB devices I want to handle.

I plan to call `supervisor:which_children/1` before each scan to find out which devices are present but have no child process running.

In order to find out which addresses have children running I plan to create Id atoms for  the childspec that contain the addresses (there are only a few addresses possible), e.g.  `adr_12` if the child handles address `12`.

When I try to start/restart missing children I have the somewhat ugly situation that the child specs are not automatically deleted when the transient child terminates or crashes (at least I think that it is so).  So I would need code like this:

```
case supervisor:start_child(my_sup, Spec) of
    {error, already_present} ->
        supervisor:restart_child(my_sup, Spec);
    Any -> Any
end
```

Then  there is the problem that I don't know if `supervisor:which_children/1` also returns already terminated children.

So it would be best if children would be deleted after they transiently terminate.

Somehow all this feels inelegant to me so I'm asking myself (and you):

How can I resolve this most elegantly?

Is it better not to use a supervisor at all in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling/knee jerk reaction is: 'You need to use a simple_one_for_one' supervisor for them, so their spec gets removed when it stops. If you need to be able to grab a specific process for communication, I would use the *gproc* application for that (or an ETS table).

Comment: problem with simple_one_for_one is that it is not easy to find out what addresses are missing a process.  I'd have to implement a separate address registry that monitors the processes.  What purpose does the simple_one_for_one supervisor serve then?

Comment: gproc sounds indeed appealing for this BTW

Comment: the simple_one_for_one supervisor is there for hooking into the processes so if some other process dies, you can gracefully shutdown the USB links. It is for cleanup, nothing else.

Comment: I see.  Thats however not my concern: for each USB device handled by a child a complete linked bunch of processes is started.  If something goes seriously wrong here the child is terminated and restarted anyway.  What happens in addition is that new devices are plugged in, and sometimes devices disappear and reappear (quite quick). I'm experimenting with a normal one_for_one supervisor with children added an removed by the scanning process (disappearance and reappearance are often at the same address and can be handled by the supervisor atonomously)

Comment: BTW: The address is not needed to grab a process for communication just to start the right USB handler (addresses are given on the fly by the OS and have nothing to do with anything useful).  I already have a separate registry for this driven by the serial numbers of the devices once I'm talking to them.

Comment: I guess it would make sense to separate maintaining one process per USB device from how to match `{VendorID,ProductID}`, device serial numbers (which may not be unique), device classes etc. to processes and back.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the children you want to dynamically add to your supervisor are very similar each other. Maybe a [simple-one-for-one](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id69721) supervisor is what you need. These supervisors are "a simplified version of the one_for_one supervisor, where all child processes are dynamically added instances of the same process.". Every child will have the same child specs, so you don't need to specify it when you call the `supervisor:add_child/2`.

Also, mind that the above idea of creating an atom (e.g. `adr_12`) dynamically could be dangerous. Atoms are limited in an Erlang system (by default ~1000000). See the documentation for details.

Comment: There are only 127 possible addresses on a USB bus, only the low addresses are ever used -> so creating an atom isn't being a problem

Comment: Sure. I just thought it was useful to mention the issue - someone might look at this question and think to use your same approach with a much bigger number of children -

Comment: Please also see my comment to @IGCA's answer